# Build fails with attribute has already been defined when constraint-layout 2.0.0-beta2 is used

Tags: android, xml, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

When I use `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2`
I get following build error.

If I use `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2`, I do not get any error.

Why am I getting these errors? How to get rid of this?

I see app:alpha was renamed to android:alpha in https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/constraintlayout-200-beta-1.html

Build fail log:

```
/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:949: AAPT: Attribute "android:alpha" has already been defined

/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:1017: AAPT: Attribute "android:translationX" has already been defined

/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:1017: AAPT: Attribute "android:translationY" has already been defined

/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:1017: AAPT: Attribute "android:translationZ" has already been defined

/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:949: error: Attribute "android:alpha" has already been defined
/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:1017: error: Attribute "android:translationX" has already been defined
/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:1017: error: Attribute "android:translationY" has already been defined
/home/user/MyApp/build/intermediates/res/merged/myFlavor/debug/values/values.xml:1017: error: Attribute "android:translationZ" has already been defined

:MyApp:processMyFlavorDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApp:processMyFlavorDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: Could you share the layout in question? Just the constraint layout would be helpful.

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: Hi, mate.
Could you provide the library you're using that is conflicting with?
Because in your case you could try to declare this library this way:

`implementation('<library>'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support.constraint', module: 'constraint-layout'
}`

Comment: I also had the same issue with 2.0.0-alpha4. I changed to use 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

update gradle plugin version higher than 3.0.1 in your project's build.gradle file.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

It works for me